# How can I extend a build class, like HTMLElement or Node, inside a typescript module?

Tags: typescript, module

This code work in a typescript file:

```
interface Node {
    replaceWith(newnode): void;
}

Node.prototype.replaceWith = function(newnode: Node) {
    this.parentElement.replaceChild(newnode, this);
};
```

It stops working as soon as the file becomes a module. So by adding this:

```
export let x = 42 // export statement turns the ts file into a module
```

the compiler complains: *Property 'replaceWith' does not exist on type*  'Node'. Why is this and how to work around?

I understand that the extension must be declared in the global "scope" and the module is no longer global enough. But while in C++ for instance I can always add brackets around a block and make it global scope, in typescript I do not see a similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global types must be declared in global if you are in a module, otherwise they will be considered just a regular module scoped type:

```
declare global {
    interface Node {
        replaceWith(newnode: Node): void;
    }    
}
Node.prototype.replaceWith = function(newnode: Node) {
    this.parentElement.replaceChild(newnode, this);
};
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.